# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Robotics Stack Exchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Tracking Landspeed Underwater](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6418/tracking-landspeed-underwater)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How does a two-gear pull-back car toy work?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/how-does-a-two-gear-pull-back-car-toy-work)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [role of chi2 in SLAM back-end optimization](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6447/role-of-chi2-in-slam-back-end-optimization)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [DH Matrix to homogeneous transformation matrix for each joint](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/dh-matrix-to-homogeneous-transformation-matrix-for-each-joint)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Ways of reversing motor direction easily](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/ways-of-reversing-motor-direction-easily)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How do you design Quadcopter PID algorithm?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6446/how-do-you-design-quadcopter-pid-algorithm)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [BeagleBone - PRU questions](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/beaglebone-pru-questions)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Low power computer for stereo vision](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6508/low-power-computer-for-stereo-vision)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to provide power to a robot/raspberry pi?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6437/how-to-provide-power-to-a-robot-raspberry-pi)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Dealing with position inaccuracy and latency in PID Loop](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6355/dealing-with-position-inaccuracy-and-latency-in-pid-loop)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---